# Update to number datatype by vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I use UPDATE query to update a value to NUMBER datatype field i get data type mismatch error

my code :

```
com.CommandText = "UPDATE register SET price_reg=@price_reg,rprice_reg=@rprice_reg,ipprice_reg=@ipprice_reg,mprice_reg=@mprice_reg,totalp_reg=@totalp_reg,operatormali_reg=@operatormali_reg,noedaryaft_reg=@noedaryaft_reg,datedaryaft_reg=@datedaryaft_reg WHERE id_reg='" & Label58.Text & "' "

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_reg", TextBox12.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rprice_reg", TextBox11.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ipprice_reg", TextBox13.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mprice_reg", TextBox14.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalp_reg", TextBox15.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operatormali_reg", username)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noedaryaft_reg", ComboBox1.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedaryaft_reg", TextBox16.Text)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

5 first parameter is NUMBER datatype in my access database

i try this for send parameters too :

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_reg", convert.toint32(TextBox12.Text))
```

also i try this :

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_reg", Cdec(TextBox12.Text))
```

also i try add :

```
 com.CommandText = "UPDATE register SET price_reg=@price_reg,rprice_reg=@rprice_reg,ipprice_reg=@ipprice_reg,mprice_reg=@mprice_reg,totalp_reg=@totalp_reg,operatormali_reg=@operatormali_reg,noedaryaft_reg=@noedaryaft_reg,datedaryaft_reg=@datedaryaft_reg WHERE id_reg='" & Label58.Text & "' "

    com.Parameters.Add("@price_reg", OleDbType.Integer)
    com.Parameters("@price_reg").Value = CInt(TextBox12.Text)

    com.Parameters.Add("@rprice_reg", OleDbType.Integer)
    com.Parameters("@rprice_reg").Value = CInt(TextBox11.Text)

    com.Parameters.Add("@ipprice_reg", OleDbType.Integer)
    com.Parameters("@ipprice_reg").Value = CInt(TextBox13.Text)

    com.Parameters.Add("@mprice_reg", OleDbType.Integer)
    com.Parameters("@mprice_reg").Value = CInt(TextBox14.Text)

    com.Parameters.Add("@totalp_reg", OleDbType.Integer)
    com.Parameters("@totalp_reg").Value = CInt(TextBox15.Text)

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operatormali_reg", username)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noedaryaft_reg", ComboBox1.Text)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedaryaft_reg", TextBox16.Text)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but same error

error msg :

```html
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147217913
  Message="Data type mismatch in criteria expression."
  Source="Microsoft JET Database Engine"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at asiatech_managment.Form1.ToolStripButton23_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\pc1\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\asiatech-managment\asiatech-managment\Form1.vb:line 360    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)    at asiatech_managment.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

thanks for your answers

Comment: Use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue` and convert the text control's text to whatever type it should be

Comment: @'s before parameters also might help

Comment: thanks Aaron for answer but not working

Comment: Plutonix thanks . but not working

Comment: don't use `covert. toint32`(not sure, but I think that is equiv. for Long datatype) try with simple `CDec(TextBox12.Text)`.

Comment: thanks nelek i try Cint but same error

Comment: i try Cdec too , not working :(

Comment: You missing sign **@** in parameters in `price_reg`, must be `@price_reg` ...  `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_reg", CDec(TextBox12.Text))` ... and, of course, use `CDec`

Comment: i add @ when Aaron said it but its not working

Comment: I doubt that the price is an integer, more likely a double or money/currency/decimal type.  Once more, dont use `AddWithValue` it makes the db provider guess what you are doing.  `id_reg` likely isnt text either

Comment: `Label58.Text` should be a parameter as well

Comment: is it `id_reg='" & Label58.Text & "'` that's causing the issue? is your id a numerical value, but you're treating it as text?

Comment: @ps2goat the first 5 params are some sort of numeric type but they are all being passed text; `noedaryaft_reg` looks like it is a date, but getting text passed as well, then there is the Id.

Comment: @Plutonix - sorry, i didn't see the last part of your previous comment.  i saw others already commenting on the decimal issues.

Comment: @ps2goat the question has "evolved" - that some are numeric is an edit

Comment: @nelek OleDb doesnt use named parameters as such, you can use any designation you want when `Add`ing them, as long as you `Add` them in the same order as they appear in the SQL  (Post is tagged Acccess, so I assume OleDB)

Comment: Plutonix please see my edited qustion

Comment: Are those columns *really* integer?  is `noedaryaft_reg` a date or text?  also what happens if they write `I like pie` in a textbox?  Did you validate what they entered?

Comment: @ps2goat i changed my WHERE to Cint(label58.text) . not working yet

Comment: @Plutonix noedaryaft_reg is text and all 5 first field is NUMBER type

Comment: you'll have to update your question with code snippets of what you've tried so far and where you currently are with your code.

Comment: The exception message also gives more details than you have given us, but as Intellisence will tell you `NUMERIC` type maps to decimal - a decimal is not an integer

Comment: @ps2goat im updating step by step with you

Comment: @Plutonix my dataset show me my fields is int32

Comment: @Plutonix can you test it by teamviewer please ?

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@price_reg", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox12.Text)` **provided** there is a valid numeric value in it and not "L33t cod3r" or some such...if they are int32, it wont save fractions

Comment: 'com.Parameters.Add("@price_reg", OleDbType.Numeric)
        com.Parameters("@price_reg").Value = CDec(TextBox12.Text)'

Comment: not working with numeric :(

Comment: You never gave us the whole error message; it has very likely been changing during all this but that is a mystery too.  Note that you said they were NUMBER which is Access version of Decimal...they cant also be Int32.  So, you can imagine why we cant tell you the magic spell to fix it

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147217913
  Message="Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: ...and the where clause that @ps2goat detailed is still wrong - you have multiple issues and seem to be trying to fix only the ones you think are a problem  (that is not the whole message - the details tell more)

Comment: ...and if you have a dataset, why arent you just adding a row to the table instead of all this???

Comment: @Plutonix i update qustion by full error msg

Comment: @Plutonix also i change where clause to Cint(label58.text)

Comment: @Plutonix - i never detailed a where clause.

Comment: @ps2goat, sorry, I was saying that the OP also didnt fix the stuff you mentioned (`id_reg='" & Label58.Text & "'`) even though they kept posting that everything is fixed and still doesnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error said

`Message="Data type mismatch in criteria expression."`

My Question is what is the datatype of your `id_reg`? is it an INT? if yes then do something like this.

change your

`WHERE id_reg='" & Label58.Text & "' "`

to

`WHERE id_reg=" & Label58.Text`

[image]

Comment: Pls see the updated answer, I gave you some key points for it

Comment: YW and Happy Coding